# Adding Html2Xhtml library to project

Tags: html, visual-studio-2008, xhtml, converters

I am trying to use HTML2XHTML but how can I include it into my project?

I am using VS2008 and I put the dlls into bin folder of my project and add Html2Xhtml to the refs, but it still does not recognize the "using Corsis.Html2Xhtml;" declaration. It gives the missing assembly  compile time error.

I included the following dll in the refs: Html2Xhtml.dll

I also added `libiconv-2.dll` to my bin folder. as well as the XML file that I think is required.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

How exactly do I add the library to my project?